# python3: can't open file '/app/app.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory - Docker

Tags: python, docker, flask, scrapy

So I'm bulding Scrapy/Flask app and I'm trying to dockerize it so I could run it with docker-compose up. I already dockerized Scrapy app. But when I tried to implement Flask web app, I'll always get that Docker can't find app/app.py.

Here is my folder structure:

```
sreality_crawler
 ┣ config
 ┃ ┣ config.py
 ┃ ┗ __init__.py
 ┣ sreality_crawler
 ┃ ┣ spiders
 ┃ ┃ ┣ sreality_spider.py
 ┃ ┃ ┗ __init__.py
 ┃ ┣ items.py
 ┃ ┣ middlewares.py
 ┃ ┣ pipelines.py
 ┃ ┣ settings.py
 ┃ ┗ __init__.py
 ┣ web_server
 ┃ ┣ templates
 ┃ ┃ ┗ index.html
 ┃ ┗ app.py
 ┣ docker-compose.yaml
 ┣ Dockerfile
 ┣ requirements.txt
 ┗ scrapy.cfg
```

Here is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:latest

WORKDIR /app

COPY requirements.txt .

RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

EXPOSE 8080

COPY . .

CMD ["python", "web_server/app.py"]
```

And here is my docker-compose.yaml:

```
version: '3'

services:
  sreality_crawler:
    build: .
    volumes:
      - ./sreality_crawler:/app/sreality_crawler
    depends_on:
      - postgres
    environment:
      - DB_HOST=postgres
      - DB_PORT=5432
      - DB_NAME=flats
      - DB_USER=postgres
      - DB_PASS=postgres
    command: ["scrapy", "crawl", "sreality"]

  postgres:
    image: postgres:latest
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_DB=flats
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
      - POSTGRES_HOST=postgres
  web_server:
    build: ./sreality_crawler/web_server:/app/sreality_crawler/web_server
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    depends_on: 
      - sreality_crawler
```

I tried to look inside of container with:
`docker run -it sreality_crawler-web_server sh`
And I could clearly see, that the file is inside [image: docker folder structure]

EDIT: Attaching CMD output:
[image: cmd output]

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: I don't understand why the error message has `/app/app.py` when the actual command seems to be `python web_server/app.py`

Comment: `CMD ["python", "web_server/app.py"]` Are you missing a slash in front of `web_server`?

Comment: @JohnGordon I don't understand it either. Attached image as proof.

Comment: @JohnGordon Tried to add slash in front of web_server. Nothing changed unfortunately.

Comment: You've set [the WORKDIR](https://docs.docker.com/reference/dockerfile/#workdir) to `/app`, so... maybe don't do that and instead set it to the directory you actually need your commands to run relative to?

Comment: hey, just to debug have you run docker image? `docker image ls` and then `docker run -it -p 8080:8080  bf39a50f6fcf  ` replace IMAGE ID with yours.